# Compiling error in Java Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, compilation, sequence, fibonacci

I am confused on why I'm getting an error and how to fix it. My version of the fibonacci sequence is supposed to only print the desired target index value, and not all the numbers before it like most other Fibonacci sequences I've seen.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci_ronhoward
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This is a Fibonacci sequence generator");

    System.out.println("Choose what you would like to do");

    System.out.println("1. Find the nth Fibonacci number");

    System.out.println("2. Find the smallest Fibonacci number that exceeds user given value");

    System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

    int choice = scan.nextInt();

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Enter the target index to generate (>1): ");

            int n = scan.nextInt();

            int a = 0;

            int b = 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {

                int nextNumber = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = nextNumber;

            }

            System.out.println("The " + n + "th Fibonacci number is " + nextNumber + " ");

            break;

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what is the error, how you are expecting us to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You define `nextNumber` in `for` loop but then try to use it outside of for loop scope, that's the problem.

You should declare it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        //PROBLEM, nextNumber goes out of scope when loop exits
        int nextNumber = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = nextNumber;
    }
    System.out.println("The " + n + "th Fibonacci number is " + nextNumber + " ");
```

Do this instead:

```
    int nextNumber = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        nextNumber = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = nextNumber;
    }
    System.out.println("The " + n + "th Fibonacci number is " + nextNumber + " ");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the second part, I have to find the smallest Fibonacci number that exceeds a user given value, but am having trouble trying to figure out how to approach it, even though I am sure that is of the same element as in this.

Answer (score 1):

`nextNumber` is defined within the loop, and so is out of scope to the System.out.println() call.